# How does the sequelize supports select query with Order by field(id, 4,1,2,5) operation

Tags: sequelize.js

I want to add the "order by field()" support for my sequelize queries. 
So will sequelize supports for this operation?
For example I've query like this

```
select * from sections sc inner join students s on s.section_id=sc.id where s.id in (505, 509, 485, 278, 374, 382, 130, 184, 257) order by FIELD(s.id,505, 509, 485, 278, 374, 382, 130, 184, 257);
```

How does the sequelize supports select query with Order by field(id, 4,1,2,5) operation

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`sequelize.literal()`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/#literalval-sequelizeliteral) to pass the exact value into the query:

```js
{
  order: sequelize.literal('FIELD(s.id ,505, 509, 485, 278, 374, 382, 130, 184, 257)'),
}
```

See the examples on this page: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/querying/#ordering